# How to replace relative path URLs with absolute path URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have HTML content stored in a database and I'm looking to convert all the relative asset references to use absolute paths instead. For instance, all of my image tags are looking something like this:

```
<img src=\"/system/images/146/original/03.png?1362691463\">
```

I'm trying to prepend `"http://example.com"` to the `"/system/images/"` path. I had the following code that I was hoping to handle that but sadly it doesn't seem to result in any changes:

```
text = "<img src=\"/system/images/146/original/03.png?1362691463\">"
text.gsub(%r{<img src=\\('|")\/system\/images\/}, "<img src=\"http://virtualrobotgames.com/system/images/")
```

Comment: You should look into using a tool designed specifically for the job: [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html). It has methods to parse URLs, change the scheme and host, mess with the path, and then spit out a string that has everything encoded correctly.

Comment: @theTinMan I love that idea, if you rephrase that as an answer I would happily accept it.

Comment: I added an expanded example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the URL string using normal string manipulation, use a tool made for the job. Ruby includes the [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class, and there's the more thorough [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem.

Here's what I'd do if I had some HTML with links I wanted to rewrite:

First, parse the document:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'uri'

SOURCE_SITE = URI.parse("http://virtualrobotgames.com")

html = '
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <img src="/system/images/146/original/03.png?1362691463">
  <script src="/scripts/foo.js"></script>
  <a href="/foo/bar.html">foo</a>
</body>
</html>
'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

Then you're in a position to walk through the document and modify tags like `<a>`, `<img>`, `<script>` and anything else that you want:

```
# find things using 'src' and 'href' parameters
tags = {
  'img'    => 'src',
  'script' => 'src',
  'a'      => 'href'
}
doc.search(tags.keys.join(',')).each do |node|

  url_param = tags[node.name]

  src = node[url_param]
  unless (src.empty?)
    uri = URI.parse(src)
    unless uri.host
      uri.scheme = SOURCE_SITE.scheme
      uri.host = SOURCE_SITE.host
      node[url_param] = uri.to_s
    end
  end
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Which, after running, outputs:

```
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
# >> <body>
# >>   <img src="http://virtualrobotgames.com/system/images/146/original/03.png?1362691463">
# >>   <script src="http://virtualrobotgames.com/scripts/foo.js"></script>
# >>   <a href="http://virtualrobotgames.com/foo/bar.html">foo</a>
# >> </body>
# >> </html>
```

This isn't meant to be a complete, fully-working, example. This is working with absolute links, but you'll have to deal with relative links, links with sibling/peer hostnames, missing parameters.

You'll also want to check the `errors` method for your "doc" after parsing to make sure it is valid HTML. A parser can rewrite/trim nodes in invalid HTML trying to make sense of it.

Comment: You can't call URI methods on a String, must be `URI(SOURCE_SITE).scheme`

Comment: To get only the html inside the body tag, use doc.at('body').inner_html

Comment: @Sidhannowe, that's why the code uses `uri = URI.parse(src)`, which parses the string into a URI object.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you, your answer helped me a lot to quickly do something very similar. @Sidhannowe was right, the code declared `uri` but tried to call `scheme` and `host` on the string declaring the url (variable `source_site`). I edited the code.

Comment: Do NOT edit code in people's answers. That misrepresents what they said. You're welcome to comment or to add a separate answer that demonstrates the difference. It appears several people edited it, getting the changes wrong. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the 'base' HTML tag to do this?. Assuming you read the HTML content directly from a URL, you could do something like:

```
response = RestClient.get(<original_url>)
base_url = '<your_base_url>'
html_content = response.body
if html_content.index('<head>')
    html_content = html_content.gsub!('<head>', "<head><base href='#{base_url}'>")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was an issue with the search argument I was passing, the escape sequences weren't required.

```
%r{<img src=\\('|")\/system\/images\/}
```

Becomes simply:

```
%r{<img src="/system/images/}
```