# Convert all link in HTML to absolute path

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a HTML string, for example,

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="/image/myimage.png"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to convert all relative path into absolute path, like this?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="http://example.com/image/myimage.png"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using Ruby on Rails, any suitable gem? Or a general way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you generating this HTML string using link_to?

Comment: just use rails url helper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace relative path urls with absolute path urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888491/replace-relative-path-urls-with-absolute-path-urls)

Answer (score 0):

This is a JS function I got some time ago, not really mine and don't remember where I found it (had it as a snippet, so credits to whoever wrote it) but it really works wonders:

```
var absolutePath = function(href) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = href;
    return (link.protocol+"//"+link.host+link.pathname+link.search+link.hash);
}
```

EDIT: looking for the author of the above snippet, found a Ruby version for you:

```
[code = ruby]
Class String
  @@base = "http://example.com"
  def to_link
    "#{@@base}/folder/#{to_s}"
  end
  def to_js
    "#{@@base}/#{to_s}"
  end
end
[/code]
```

then puts `"<a href = #{'link.html'.to_link}>some link</a>"`

From [Rails Forum](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=6638)

Answer (score 0):

**URL**

You'll likely be looking for the `_url` helpers.

The difference between the `_path` and `_url` helpers is the `_url` helpers will load the absolute path, whereas `_path` will be relative to your current URL. Here's a [great resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350539/what-is-the-difference-between-url-and-path-while-using-the-routes-in-rails):

> *_path are for views because ahrefs are implicitly linked to the current URL. So it’d be a waste of bytes to repeat it over and over.
>   In the controller, though, *_url is needed for redirect_to because the
>   HTTP specification mandates that the Location: header in 3xx redirects
>   is a complete URL.

This means, judging from your question, that you'll be best suited to [changing any of your `_path` references to `_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html):

```
<%= link_to "", image_url("myimage.png") %>
```